# MySQL store procedure use select responce in INSERT...SELECT where in array

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am pretty sure that this is a simple matter and that it's answered but I seems like not able to find it online, or to phrase it correctly.

I have a table (`ven_data`) that has a few columns: `id_v`, `lang`, more data columns
The unique constraint here is `(id_v, lang)` pair.

I need to find all ID's that have some languages missing, and then `INSERT...SELECT` from one of the languages to all the missing languages.

What I do now, I am fetching ALL ID's that has less then the number of languages I need:

```
SELECT id_v, COUNT( 1 ) as cnt
FROM  `ven_data` 
GROUP BY id_v
HAVING cnt <8
ORDER BY cnt ASC
```

Then I export it to Notepadd++ and remove all unneeded data, make a line of ID's like this: 1,4,5,6

And then make the INSERT...SELECT

```
INSERT INTO `ven_data`(`id_v`, `lang`, data columns)
SELECT `id_v`, elementInner, data columns 
FROM `ven_data` WHERE `id_v` in (1,4,5,6) and `lang` = element
        on duplicate key update lang=elementInner;
```

Now I have not problem iterating over the languages in the stored procedure but how do I get the result of the first SQL into the `id_v` in (1,4,5,6) ???

Answer (score 0):

I'll choose to make the database generate a (virtual) table with all `(id_v, lang)` pairs that you are expected to have at the end.

To do so, you start by getting the list (actually *set*) of all `DISTINCT lang`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    lang
FROM
    ven_data ;
```

... and let's imagine it is this one

```
| lang |
| :--- |
| EN   |
| FR   |
| IT   |
| CA   |
| DE   |
| DK   |
| GR   |
| NL   |
```

We do the same to get the set of all `DISTINCT id_v`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id_v
FROM
    ven_data ;
```

```
| id_v |
| ---: |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   11 |
|   12 |
|   13 |
```

What should be in your `ven_data` table is actually the *cartesian product* of both sets. That is accomplished in SQL by means of a [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php).

That results in:

```
id_v | lang
---: | :---
   1 | EN  
   2 | EN  
   3 | EN  
   4 | EN  
   8 | EN  
   9 | EN  
  11 | EN  
  12 | EN  
  13 | EN  
   [...]
   1 | NL  
   2 | NL  
   3 | NL  
   4 | NL  
   8 | NL  
   9 | NL  
  11 | NL  
  12 | NL  
  13 | NL
```

What you actually want to do is `INSERT` in your table *all the rows in this cartesian product that aren't already there*.

You do this by means of:

```
INSERT INTO 
    ven_data
    (id_v, lang)
SELECT
    id_v, lang
FROM
    -- The whole set of (id_v, lang) pairs
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        lang
    FROM
        ven_data
    ) AS languages
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        id_v
    FROM
        ven_data
    ) AS id_list
WHERE
    -- The pair (id_v, lang) is not already in place
    NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 
        1
    FROM 
        ven_data v2
    WHERE 
        v2.id_v = id_list.id_v AND v2.lang = languages.lang
    ) ;
```

Note that this `WHERE` condition can also be written in more than one fashion (in MySQL):

```
WHERE
    (id_v, lang) NOT IN
    (SELECT 
        id_v, lang
    FROM 
        ven_data v2
    ) ;
```

You can see the whole setup (together with all the steps 1 by 1) and you can experiment at
*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=82cb6e2238cc49751fc26afb778f88d8)*

---

NOTEs: you don't need to do this from a stored procedure, nor you need to use arrays. This code is quite standard SQL. Note that it also works with *[PostgreSQL](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=82cb6e2238cc49751fc26afb778f88d8)*  or *[SQL Server](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=82cb6e2238cc49751fc26afb778f88d8)*, for instance.

---

Comment: So you are say that I should iterate over each of the pair's and not work over an array of elements? But would not it create a longer run? We are talking about something like 2-3 thousands of sql commands, not counting the original table creation. And not a mear 8 commands in the case of the array.

Comment: P.S. so as the above set, not requiering a Stored Procedure, but I would like to have one to be called if needed.

Comment: No. I say *do not iterate at all*. Whenever you use a database and you iterate... *you're probably not using all the power of the database*. The last `INSERT` does everything in just one (from a programmer's perspective) step.  It gets some practicing, but try *not* to think in terms of *rows*. Think in terms of *tables* (lots of rows at once). The concept of *row* is straightforward if your programming in PHP, they *map* quite easily to one associative array. *Tables* aren't as straighforward and require a bit more of abstraction.

Comment: If you need to put this into a stored procedure... it's ok. It will just have one statement.

Comment: I see your point, but the problem is that I need all the data columns that are in addition, and they are in the 1 line I do have...

Comment: In your case I created a cros-join of the lang list and the ID's list, but when I do the insert I need much more columns there... with all the data. that are soming from one of the languages, and I do not really know in advance which one.

Comment: Think which is your criterion for the other data... and `JOIN` one more time: `JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.lang = languages.lang AND ...whatever...`, you'll have all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be equivalent to your two queries:

```
INSERT
     INTO  `ven_data`(`id_v`, `lang`, data columns) 
SELECT  `id_v`, elementInner, data columns
    FROM  `ven_data` AS v
    JOIN ( SELECT  id_v
            FROM  `ven_data`
            GROUP BY  id_v
            HAVING  COUNT(*) < 8
         ) AS x  USING(id_v)
    WHERE  `lang` = element
ON duplicate key UPDATE  lang = elementInner;
```

(However, I don't understand `element` and `elementInner`.

It will perform the subquery to find the 4 id_v values, then join to ven_data to get ther rest of the columns.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can advise on what index to have.

Comment: The element and elementInner is my way to iterate over all languages. I am just using 2 while loops on in the other to loop over all languages multiple times (outer loop is from what language the inner loop to what lanugage to insert)